# VS Code Vetur extension failing to read VueJS with InertiaJS files

Tags: performance, vue.js, visual-studio-code, inertiajs, vetur

I started working on a new Laravel, Vue and inertiaJS project and I'm using VS code editor. The problem I'm having is that Vetur isn't getting that I'm using Inertia not pure Vue components; therefore, It keeps on highlighting everything in red because It assumes that everything is unidentified and unknown.

The below image is to demonstrate what I mean:

[image: VS Code showing errors]

Is there a way I can work with InertiaJS on VS Code without having these disturbing errors everywhere and see only valid errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vetur is deprecated, which is likely the cause of the problem. Switch to Volar.

From the [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#ide-support):

> ###### TIP
>
> [Volar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.volar) replaces [Vetur](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur), our previous official VSCode extension for Vue 2. If you have Vetur currently installed, make sure to disable it in Vue 3 projects.